# Multi tenancy design - sharing data between schemas

Tags: sql, database, multi-tenant

Let's consider such case:

1. User can have a company (or many of them)
2. User can be a part of a company (or in many of them)
3. Company is a single tenant of the system
4. Company has a list of tasks
5. Each task is assigned to a user

Now given the circumnstaces above, I want to implement a system in which each company (tenant) has a separate schema for its tasks, but the problem is that for each task I also need a user data from the main schema.

The question is how to approach this problem

The possible solutions I have thought of (but none is really convincing me):

1. Copying all users data matched with a company to company's schema (it would require a fair amount of synchronization, therefore I don't find it very efficient)
2. Switching between schemas and 'merging' them programmatically - this one involves a lot of additional code to implement and it violates good practices - as the user_id in task would reach outside the tanant's schema)

I hope there is a better solution I haven't thought of. Please note that this is a simplified case, just to describe the problem.

Comment: Or 3, don't use schemas to separate tenant data.

Comment: I don't think this is good neither. With increasingly big amount of users and companies (and tasks) this would be ineffective to search through tasks to query the ones belonging to a given company.

Comment: Indexes... use them.  DBs are really good at finding data, provided you have a proper design and indexes.  Or do one of your two suggestions, which will be a maintenance and performance nightmare.

Comment: Yes, but there's still a huge computational discrepancy between the one schema and separate ones. And the maintenance is yet another reason why I really want to avoid the two solutions and if no other approach will appear, one schema is the the way to go.

Comment: Two identical tables which differ only by schema are two different tables as far as the DB is concerned.  You'll be building custom UNION queries to get what you want, so kiss your plan cache goodbye.  Schema per customer becomes unmaintainable very quickly.

Comment: Why would I build UNION queries? I don't want to share any data between customers' schemas, just between a customer's schema and the main schema (the main schema is unique and shared throughout the whole system)

Comment: If you want to get tasks from more than one company, and each company gets their own schema, how do you think you'll do it without building UNION queries?  Or are you going to "merge" the data in code after selecting from X tables.. (and why would you do that when at least you can let the DB server do it).

Comment: The thing is I don't want to get tasks from more than one company.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I want to get a user for a given task, where the user table is in the main schema, but the task table is in tenant's schema

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a handful of tables, like `users`, `companies`, `tasks`, and related tables.

In general, you do not want to split entities across multiple tables.  Here are some reasons.

1. It is easier to maintain a handful of tables rather than hundreds or thousands of tables.
2. Databases are *more* efficient on larger tables. A proliferation of small tables results in lots of partially filled data pages for a single entity.
3. Certain queries -- such as how many tasks are in each company -- are much easier with a single table.
4. With multiple tables, such queries often require resorting to dynamic SQL, which is just a mess for simple tasks.
5. Restructuring the data becomes a nightmare when you have to apply the restructuring to a zillion tables rather than a handful of tables.
6. Adding new features is a nightmare when it has to be repeated multiple times.

There are some rare circumstances where it makes sense to separate data.  For instance, if the application is going to be on-premise at each company, then you have no choice.  Similarly, you might have legal requirements for keeping data physically separate.  But from a strict database-design perspective, you want one table per entity.

Comment: I assume the downvoter disagrees with these points.  S/he should specify the reasons in a comment.

Comment: Thank you, You've clarified why it is better to actually have one schema.